# Hide type's nature

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

To learn linked lists' (doubly-linked) conception I'm writing a bunch of simple common functions to handle them. Most of the functions take pointer to the DL_List
structure, which is the handle and contains not only links to the first and last elements but also current position in the list.

```
       typedef struct DL_Node {
               struct DL_Node *next = NULL;
               struct DL_Node *prev = NULL;

               int data;
       } DL_Node;

       typedef struct DL_List {
               struct DL_Node *first = NULL;
               struct DL_Node *last  = NULL;

               struct DL_Node *cur   = NULL;
       } DL_List;
```

Therefore I always have to pass a pointer to the handle.

```
   int main() {...
       DL_List list; // lives on the stack

       init_list(&list, 9);
       push(&list, 7);
       append(&list, 10);
       insert_after(&list, -31);
       print_list(&list);
   ...}
```

So here is the question: is there any way to avoid rereading passing `&list`? Maybe typedefing?

[github repo](https://github.com/Aenry/DoublyLinkedLists)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It is preferable if you post syntactically correct code, unlike the code above where every single occurrence of `= NULL` should produce a compilation error. What is it that you want to avoid? Repeatedly passing `&list` to the functions? No; you can't avoid that in C — unless you do something horribly uncouth and inflexible like use a global variable. If you use C++, you could avoid it by writing `list.init(9);` etc; you'd still mention `list` each time, but you wouldn't need the `&`.

Comment: Ah, that's a pity there is no way of getting rid of the &. Don't think using globals would be nice. Thank you for your answer. I'll read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
int main() {...
   DL_List list; // lives on the stack
   DL_List * plist = &list;

   init_list(plist, 9);
   push(plist, 7);
   append(plist, 10);
   insert_after(plist, -31);
   print_list(plist);
...}
```

if you want to avoid typing `&`, but it doesn't really save you something.

A good compiler should optimize this away.

Comment: Well, this is going to be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using global variables or horrendous macros, no. You explicitly pass as arguments the objects you want a function to operate on.